# Is it possible to recover most application files and data from the apk?

Tags: android

Having deleted entire project folders, is it possible to recover most of the data and resources from a copy of your application's .apk file found online?

If so, which tools can best be used to achieve this?

Comment: They are called Decompilers, and there are some pretty good ones for Android. Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if it's possible to completely rebuild an android project from an apk, but I know depending on the release status of the apk it might be a lot harder. Android has a feature called 'Proguard' that obfuscates and simplifies release versions of apps. (see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)). Tldr; it's going to be a lot harder if it's a release version.

Comment: side note: proguard is both independent and much (much) older that android. It can obfuscate and shrink any java.

Comment: How is that in any way related to what I just said?

Comment: @Skyfall If you're talking to me, because it's a barrier that could stand in your way and it's something to look out for. If you're talking about njzk2's answer, not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decode the resources from an APK.